# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 4, size is 4

Tags: java, android, android-adapter

Não sei bem o que está acontecendo, quando eu dou um long click em um item da lista, as vezes funciona normalmente (abre uma tela onde mostra ao usuário as informações cadastradas, permitindo que ele as altere), as vezes o app para e fecha e as vezes o app para e abre uma página de cadastro setando os valores nos respectivos campos.

Código que abre a tela de detalhes do item cadastrado:

```
cDAO.abrirBanco();
contatoArray = cDAO.consultar();

lvContatos.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Contato c = contatoArray.get(i);

        Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TelaDetalhe.class);
        it.putExtra("contato", c);
        startActivity(it);

        return true;
    }
});
```

Pego o objeto enviado assim:

```
final Contato c = (Contato) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("contato");
```

Se precisar coloco mais partes do código

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O erro indica que está a tentar usar um índice fora do intervalo.

Neste caso está a usar o índice 4 enquanto o array só tem 4 itens. Lembre que a numeração dos índices começa em `0`.

A razão para isso acontecer é que o array `contatoArray` tem menos itens do que o array gerido pelo adapter.

Apenas com os elementos disponíveis na pergunta não me é possível acrescentar mais nada.

Comment: o que mais precisa?

Comment: A parte onde é construído o adapter. Para saber se é o contatoArray que é passado ao adapter e, se sim, se ele é "lido" mais alguma vez depois de ter sido passado.

Comment: Não sei se é isso que quer saber, mas o contatoArray contem um arraylist que vem direto da query de busca da classe DAO não passa pelo adapter da listview

Comment: Se não passa, então não pode usá-lo para obter o "Contato" correspondente ao item da ListView clicado. A não ser que os dois estejam de alguma forma "sincronizados".

Comment: Não o que eu fiz mas o problema foi resolvido, obrigado mesmo assim